# Transforming columns to rows in SSIS

Tags: sql, pivot, ssis

My data looks like

```
Viral Impressions   Paid Impressions    Organic Impressions
123                   5678                          34566
```

I want it to be in this format.

```
         Impressions
Viral        123
Paid         5678
Organic       34566
```

How do i do that in SSIS using Pivot unpivot

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the UNPIVOT, you can use UNION ALL:

```
 Select 'viral' as col, [viral impressions] as impressions
 From yourtable
 Union all
 Select 'paid' as col, [paid impressions] as impressions
 From yourtable
 Union all
 Select 'organic' as col, [organic impressions] as impressions
 From yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/655a5/1)

Gives the result:

```
|     COL | IMPRESSIONS |
-------------------------
|   viral |         123 |
|    paid |        5678 |
| organic |       34566 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNPIVOT` table operator:

```
SELECT 
  value, 
  Impressions
FROM TableName
UNPIVOT
(
  Impressions
  FOR value IN([Viral], 
               [Paids], 
               [Organic])
) u;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98aa8/1)

This assuming that the columns' names are stored as `Viral | Paid | Organic`. If these columns' names are `Viral Impressions |  Paid Impressions  |  Organic Impressions` Then you can do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT value, Impressions
  FROM Table1
  UNPIVOT
  (
     Impressions
     FOR value IN([Viral Impressions], 
                  [Paid Impressions], 
                  [Organic Impressions])
  ) u
)
SELECT 
  REPLACE(value, ' Impressions', '') Value, 
  Impressions
FROM CTE;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd268/4)